# select a range of values from a matrix and swap them

Tags: matlab, matrix, range, swap

I have a matrix and i want to select a range of elements.
for example i want to select all the elements that are lower than 182 and swap/change them.
does someone know an easy way or command to do this in matlab ?

thanx

Comment: with an other value or with 'NaN' so that it is regarded as an element with no value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say "swap", I understand you mean a vector, not a matrix. You can do it as follows:

```
x = [ 1 34 66 22 200 55 301 ]; % data
[ values, ind ] = find(x<182);
x(ind) = x(ind(end:-1:1));
```

To simply replace them by another value such as NaN, do as follows. Note that this works also for matrices:

```
x = [ 1 34 66 22 200 55 301 ]; % data
x(x<182) = NaN;
```

Answer (score 1):

Such things can usually be accomplished via [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
A = randn(1,100);
B = randn(size(A));
test = (A>1|A<0);   % For example, values that are greater than 1 or less than 0
A(test) = B(test);
```

or another example:

```
A = randn(1,100);
test = (A>1|A<0);
A(test) = randn(1,nnz(test));
```

or another:

```
A = randn(1,100);
A(A>1|A<0) = NaN;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use  loop like this:

```
   for i = 1:length(matrix(:,1))
        for j = 1:length(matrix(1,:))
            if matrix(i,j) < 182
               matrix(i,j) = NaN;
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: Never ever consider loops in Matlab before you (1) tried all you can to vectorise the problem and (2) asked here how to vectorise the problem.

Comment: @texnic Though the second answer by Luis is definately better, this one also gets the job done. As the asker did not mention vectorization or efficiency I don't think a downvote is in place here.